# What does integration of g(x)f(x)dx mean with known bounds?

Tags: probability, integration

What does $\int_{0}^{a}g(x)f(x)dx$ mean if $f(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$?

I do know $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf(x)dx$ is the expected value of $X$, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function). But I am not sure how to interpret when bounds are given.

Comment: You misquote the Wikipedia article.  It says $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\,dx$ is the expected value of $X$, not the expected value of $x$.  The random variable (capital) $X$ and the bound variable (lower-case) $x$ are two different things.  You would become very confused if you thought they were the same.

Comment: I changed $x$ to $X$. I should check the difference, as I don't know actually.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for an interpration in English. E.g. something like "$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)f(x)dx$ is the Expected value of $g(x)$ being in the interval $[a,b]$"

Comment: I also changed "... is the probability density function of $x$" to "... is the probability density function of $X$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
{\rm E}[g(X)\mathbf{1}_{0<X<a}]
$$

Comment: An what does this mean? In English if possible, as obviously I am not well versed in the language of math.

Comment: It means that the integral $\int_0^a g(x)f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is the mean (or expected value) of the random variable $Y=g(X)\mathbf{1}_{0<X<a}$.

Comment: $X$ was representing demand for the the goods supplied to a market, whereas $a$ was the supplied amount assigned by a supply chain management software. The integral was actually $\int_{0}^{a}(a-x)C(x)f(x)d(x)$ where $C(x)$ is an inventory cost function. Going by your explanation, the integral means, expected value of the $(a-X)C(X)\bf{1}_{0<X<a}$. And that would be interpreted as "expected value of the inventory cost when demand is less than supply". Do you think I am correct?

Comment: @ozi: I agree that $\mathbf{1}_{0<X<a}$ is "when demand is less than supply and demand is positive", but I'm not sure what $(a-X)C(X)$ can be interpreted as.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Given $X$ a random variable with pdf $f$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)dx = \mathbb{E}\left[g(X) \right],$$
$$\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)I_{[a,b]}(x)f(x)dx =  \mathbb{E}\left[g(X) I_{[a,b]}(X)\right],$$
where indicator function $I_{[a,b]}(x)$ is $1$ if $x\in [a,b]$, and $0$ otherwise. On the sample space $\Omega$, $g(X)(\omega) = g(X(\omega))$ and $ I_{[a,b]}(X)(\omega)  = I_{[a,b]}(X(\omega)))$.